# Spring Security 5.3.2 - how to add oauth2-login to existing Security Configuration?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have an existing application that has its own authentication scheme, which basically does a catch-all like this:

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        ... form login config ...
```

Now I want to add a new module to this application with OAuth2-Login and I did this:

```
<sec:http pattern="/module/**" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/module/**" access="authenticated"/>
    <sec:oauth2-login/>
</sec:http>

... more OAuth2 Config ...
```

When I access an URL like `/module/something`, I am now redirected to `/oauth2/authorization/myClientId`, which I believe is a Spring Security internal URL. However, the catch-all configuration grabs that request and sends me to its form login page. How can I tell Spring Security to circumvent other configurations for its own internal URLs?

I have already tried something like this:

```
<sec:http pattern="/oauth2/**" auto-config="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth2/**" access="permitAll"/>
</sec:http>
```

But that didn't continue the OAuth2 Login process. The request went to some unrelated controller, which threw up, because there was no authenticated user (obviously).

So can I put something in the above configuration to tell Spring Security to go on with the OAuth2-Login process? I assume there's an internal controller somewhere in Spring Security that deals with `/oauth2/**` requests and I must somehow get my request to it.

By the way, my OAuth2-Login configuration does work standalone, it's the integration that stumps me.

Answer (score 0):

After much deliberation I found out that I don't even need to intercept any URL or do a permitAll. I just need to tell Spring the login mechanism to use. So the trick is to repeat the oauth2-login configuration for all internal OAuth2 URLs:

```
<sec:http pattern="/oauth2/**" auto-config="false">
    <sec:oauth2-login access-token-response-client-ref="accessTokenResponseClient"/>
</sec:http>

<sec:http pattern="/login/oauth2/**" auto-config="false">
    <sec:oauth2-login access-token-response-client-ref="accessTokenResponseClient"/>
</sec:http>
```

Note: this is just an example, your oauth2-login configuration may look different. In particular you may not have a custom OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient.